# Formatting problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to workout how to center my webpage. Currently I am using tables inside tables to break up my website, but I would like the first 1/3 of my page to go across the whole page but the other 2/3 to stay in the center. Thanks for any help! (See code below)

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>R.P.E Limited</title>
                        <style>
                                .container {
                                  float: center
                                }

                                .left {
                                  float:left;
                                }

                                .right {
                                  float:right;
                                }

                                html, body{
                               height: 100%;
                               min-height: 100%;
                                }


                                .top {
                                height: 10%;
                                }

                                .mid {
                                height: 45%;
                                }

                                .bot {
                                height: 45%;
                                }

                                body {
                                width:90%;
                                }
                        </style>
                </head>
                    <body>
                        <table height="100%" width=250%>
                          <tr>                                                      <!--Webpage start-->                            
                            <td>                                                    <!--LEAVE BLANK-->
                            </td>
                                <td>                                                <!--All code goes in here-->
                                    <table height="100%" width=100%>


                                        <td class="left" width=20%>                 <!--Left blank-->
                                        </td>



                                        <td class="container" width=60%>

                                            <table class="top" height="100%">       <!--THE PAGE STARTS HERE-->
                                                <tr><td>Top</td></tr>               <!--TOP-->
                                            </table>

                                            <table class="mid" height="100%">
                                                <tr><td>Mid</td></tr>               <!--MID-->
                                            </table>

                                            <table class="bot" height="100%">
                                                <tr><td>Bot</td></tr>               <!--BOTTOM-->
                                            </table>
                                        </td>




                                        <td class="right" width=20%>                <!--Right blank-->
                                        </td>

                                    </table>
                                </td>                                               <!--All code ends here-->
                            <td>                                                    <!--LEAVE BLANK-->
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>                                                    <!--Webpage end-->
                    </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Start over and use CSS. There is no good reason to format the display of a site using tables anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately i have no knowledge of how to format pages with CSS is there a link you can provide me so that i can find out how? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use tables for layout, use structural elements (div, article, section, aside etc) with css instead. http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: Just Google it, thats how most of us learn.  :-)

Comment: WOW, its 1995 all over again!

Comment: You can use Bootstrap: http://www.getbootstrap.com  That is a great framework to  develop responsive websites.  It has a lot of best practices to apply styles and more.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/

Answer (score 0):

Using styles as people have mentioned is the correct way. Tables should not be used for purely layout purposes.

This should be essentially what you're looking for:

```
<style>

.maincanvas {
  margin:0px auto;
  width: 600px
}

</style>


<div class="maincanvas">

   <p>This container will be centered with a width of 600px</p>

</div>
```